# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.internal.module.ModuleReferenceImpl.descriptor()

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-11

I'm getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.internal.module.ModuleReferenceImpl.descriptor()` error while executing `mvn clean intall` in my `intellij IDE`.

It's started to happen when I downgraded my `jdk-11.0.2` to `jdk1.8.0_191`.

here is the complete stackTrace:

```
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.internal.module.ModuleReferenceImpl.descriptor()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2476)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.utils.DependencyStatusSets.getModuleDescriptor(DependencyStatusSets.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.utils.DependencyStatusSets.buildArtifactListOutput(DependencyStatusSets.java:227)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.utils.DependencyStatusSets.getOutput(DependencyStatusSets.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.resolvers.ResolveDependenciesMojo.doExecute(ResolveDependenciesMojo.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

and my `mvn version` details are here :

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro:carot jangbahadurpatel$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-25T00:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

What to do to figure it out?

Comment: Please share the exact `mvn -version` and the phase where this fails. Also, your maven configurations would help here to reproduce this.

Comment: @nullpointer I have updated my question with mvn version.

Comment: Seems like your maven is configured with `Java11` while you're trying to compile code with `Java-8` instead. Details of configurations in `pom.xml` could clarify I believe.

Comment: I can't see java related configuration in my pom.xml. It's all jersey, spring-web and other dependencies but not java or jdk related configuration.

Comment: Then some defaults would be getting used, just go through the maven output on your console. It displays the versions of the plugins used. You could possibly find an incompatible version there.

Comment: should I un-install jdk-11 and jdk-8 and retry with jdk-8 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186829/discussion-between-jabongg-and-nullpointer).

Comment: Not precisely, you can configure your `mavenrc` to use JDK8 for you or else ensure there is proper `toolchains.xml` present in your maven configuration. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html

Comment: mavenrc example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118716/fatal-error-compiling-invalid-flag-module-path/46119209#46119209

Answer (score 0):

> What it's started to happen when I downgraded my `jdk-11.0.2` to
>   `jdk1.8.0_191`.

This + `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` is actually pretty suspicious. The class `ModuleReferenceImpl` is an extended class of `ModuleReference`, [which was available since Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleReference.html).

Comment: But it’s strange to see that maven uses `getDeclaredMethod` on the implementation class, to access a method defined by the interface. It looks very much like the caller is aware that the interface does not exist in this version, whereas the class `ModuleReferenceImpl` obviously exists, as the JRE only complain about the method not being present in that class.